# Is Hat Dash a game?

Tags: discussion, winterbash

Assuming I am an avid gamer, desiring to collect all the hats, treating the hat dash like a game.

Is there any reason I couldn't discuss strategies for this game on gaming itself, or does the fact that it's being run on gaming make it "meta" even though it is a game, and different strategies might yield better results with less work?

Comment: This is like a meta meta meta question!

Comment: woa............. where is meta.meta.gaming.stackexchange.com

Comment: I regret that I have but one upvote to give to this masterwork of a question.

Answer (score 5):

I think you could consider the entirety of Gaming.SE to be a game.  We earn "points" and "badges" for completing objectives, and we "level up" at times and unlock new privileges.

The hat dash is just an extension of the game-like system that's already in place.

To my mind, the accepted place to discuss the "game" that is Gaming.SE is here on meta, where we play a game of talking about the game we're playing on the main site.  (yo dawg, etc)

Now I'm risking an infinite recursion though, I should stop before I stack overflow.  Oh god, and it just goes deeper!  (Inception reference goes here)

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow is a gamified website. Does it make discussion about Stack Overflow on-topic on Gaming?

...perhaps. Still, meta is the place to ask about them. :)

If your question really does treat hat dash like a game, you can certainly give the main site a go. Worst that happens, it'll be migrated here.

Comment: That's not the worse that could happen... we could call him names... horrible horrible names

Comment: @JuanManuel No!  Not that!  Anything but that!